# Moving files from one location to another

Tags: c#, file, directory, location, move

I'm trying to make this program that will move (cut and paste) all files from one directory (a folder) to another directory. In this example, I'm trying to move all the files that are inside the D:\Source folder (has a few files in it) to C:\Source folder (which has no files in it). When I run the program, I get this error.

http://s13.postimg.org/kuufg0gmu/error.jpg

Here is the full source code:

```
using System.IO;    
namespace FileManager
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        string sourceDirectory = "";
        //string destinationDirectory = @"C:\Destination";
        string date = "";
        string[] filePaths;
        string destinationPath;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void buttonClean_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Get source directory
            sourceDirectory = textBoxDirectory.Text;
            // Get date of files
            date = textBoxDate.Text;
            // Get file paths
            if (Directory.Exists(sourceDirectory))
            {
                filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@sourceDirectory, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
                foreach (string sourcePath in filePaths)
                {
                    destinationPath = sourcePath.Remove(0, 1).Insert(0, "C");

                    File.Copy(sourcePath, destinationPath);

                    //MessageBox.Show(destinationPath);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Directory does not exist.");
            }    
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the actual text from the error, not a random image link, you should also try to only include code related to the actual problem you are having.

Comment: FYI, you are using `File.Copy`, it will not cut-paste files

Comment: there is no move method available you have to copy the file then delete it your self because the moving process is really copying then deleting, and you have to do that your self

Answer (score 2):

You need to check if destination directory exists than copy files otherwise first create destination directory.

```
foreach (string sourcePath in filePaths)
 {
  destinationPath = sourcePath.Remove(0, 1).Insert(0, "C");
   if(!Directory.Exists(destinationPath))
      Directory.CreateDirectory(destinationpath);
  File.Copy(sourcePath, destinationPath);
  //MessageBox.Show(destinationPath);
 }
```

Comment: This looks like the answer to me. Very minor point: Strictly speaking the very first thing `Directory.CreateDirectory()` does is to check whether it already exists, so you can omit the checking part in the code.

Comment: @MatthewWatson thnaks for this info.I didn't know this.

Comment: @MatthewWatson but i think it is necessary here because destination directory may only be a single directory and if we create directory without checking and directory already exist it will raise exception.

Comment: No, it won't because the implementation of `Directory.CreateDirectory()` checks first if the directory already exists, and just returns if it does - it won't throw an exception.

Comment: I should have mentioned that this information is in [the documentation for `Directory.CreateDirectory()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54a0at6s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Exception clearly states that `destinationPath` is not valid. Make sure `destinationPath` exist as shown by  @Mairaj then use `File.Move` to cut-paste. Complete code to move one file. You can your logic of directories to move all the files.

```
using System;
using System.IO;

class Test 
{
    public static void Main() 
    {
        string path = @"c:\temp\MyTest.txt";
        string path2 = @"c:\temp2\MyTest.txt";
        try 
        {
            if (!File.Exists(path)) 
            {
                // This statement ensures that the file is created, 
                // but the handle is not kept. 
                using (FileStream fs = File.Create(path)) {}
            }

            // Ensure that the target does not exist. 
            if (File.Exists(path2)) 
            File.Delete(path2);

            // Move the file.
            File.Move(path, path2);
            Console.WriteLine("{0} was moved to {1}.", path, path2);

            // See if the original exists now. 
            if (File.Exists(path)) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The original file still exists, which is unexpected.");
            } 
            else 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The original file no longer exists, which is expected.");
            }           

        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The process failed: {0}", e.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Find more info [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.move%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)